# how to show data value on bar chart body rather than using tooltip?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

i am using vue-chart for making a bar-chart. I want to show the values on bar chart body rather then using tooltip? for this what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some code so we can see what your options look like?

In general though. In your options you can configure the different axis. The data would display on the chart body and tooltip by default. Do you have something like this in your code?

```
yAxes:[{
    display:false,
}],
```

You can also disable the tooltip if you'd like by adding the following to your options.

```
tooltips: {
    enabled: false
}
```

Comment: I want to show the value of y axis on the bar-chart body rather then on the tooltip

Comment: if I disable the tooltip and then how do I show the data of the tool tip on the bars of the chart